# How to compress plots in R for use with Sweave?

Tags: r, plot, sweave

I have several images in a Sweave report that look like this:

[image]

They are created by a function with a code akin to this:

```
<<fig = T>>=
barplot(prop.table(table(x, y), margin = 2) * 100,
        border = F, xlab = '', ylab = '', las = 2)
@
```

I want to compress the y-axis, so my plot looks something like this (without the label distortion):

[image]

The only way I was able to get this was by using `png()` with a custom height parameter and then using the image file on LaTeX, but that kind of ruins the whole purpose of Sweave. How can I achieve this within `barplot()` (or with `par()` or some other elegant solution)?

Comment: Have you tried the `din` and `fin` arguments to `par`? Just taking a guess here.

Comment: `knitr` conveniently lets you define the width and height of the plots for each chunk.

Comment: Try `<<fig = T,fig.width=8,fig.height=6,res=300>>=
barplot(prop.table(table(x, y), margin = 2) * 100,
        border = F, xlab = '', ylab = '', las = 2)
@` using knitr

Comment: Yihue listed the lack of an `Sweave` capacity to control sizes of  plots as one of the main motivations of writing `knitr`. I'm guessing Sweavers typically export to a .ps or pdf using height and width specs and then import for publishing.

Comment: Thanks for the tips, I've never used knitr, but will take a look into it. I have a feeling Sweave will be giving me many headaches in this project I'm starting.

Comment: @DWin I recall that was to do with the pain of having to control both the size of the R device at create time plus the size of the final rendered image once processed via LaTeX. From what I read in the Q there is nothing there that cannot be done with Sweave's `width` and `height` chunk options.

Comment: @baptiste ...as does Sweave... and with 8 less characters too :P

Comment: So another guess: Using the method illustrated on pg4 of http://www.statistik.tuwien.ac.at/public/filz/students/SweaveExa.pdf would be the answer.

Comment: @DWin Indeed, but for full control, you'll probably want to set `width` and `height` to exactly the right sizes and then set that same `width` in `\setkeys{Gin}{width=6in}`

Comment: @GavinSimpson Sweave.styx wasn't found last time I dipped my toe in those waters.

Comment: @baptiste You need to add the local texmf tree supplied with an R install to your texmf or explicitly tell LaTeX to load the package by providing the full path.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sweave has chunk options `width` and `height` for the dimensions of the images. It won't control how big the plot is in the final rendered PDF as that is something LaTeX controls, but it does control the creation of the figures themselves.

From the [Sweave Manual](http://www.stat.uni-muenchen.de/~leisch/Sweave/Sweave-manual.pdf) [pdf]:

> Attention: One thing that gets easily confused are the `width`/`height` parameters of the R
>   graphics devices and the corresponding arguments to the LaTeX `\includegraphics` command.
>   The Sweave options `width` and `height` are passed to the R graphics devices, and hence affect
>   the default size of the produced EPS and PDF files. They do not affect the size of figures in the document, by default they will always be 80% of the current text width. Use `\setkeys{Gin}` to modify figure sizes or use explicit `\includegraphics` commands in combination with Sweave option `include=FALSE`.

Also read

```
require("utils")
?RweaveLatex
```

which also has details.

For your quoted example, `width` and `height` are both `6`, the default. So you could do something like

```
<<fig=TRUE, width=8, height=5>>=
barplot(prop.table(table(x, y), margin = 2) * 100,
        border = FALSE, xlab = '', ylab = '', las = 2)
@
```

To get the desired proportions.

[*Please* don't use `F` and `T` - you are asking for trouble!]

However, do note what the Manual or `?RweaveLatex` say. Once in LaTeX by default the image will be included with a width equal to `0.8\textwidth`. Hence you might also wish to set the width for each chunk explicitly to the size of the figure created, e.g.

```
\setkeys{Gin}{width=8in}
<<fig=TRUE, width=8, height=5>>=
barplot(prop.table(table(x, y), margin = 2) * 100,
        border = FALSE, xlab = '', ylab = '', las = 2)
@
%% reset if you want
\setkeys{Gin}{width=0.8\textwidth}
```

So you have to manage the two settings:

1. The sweave chunk options `width` and `height` control creation of the EPS or PDF file (or both)
2. `\setkeys{Gin}` controls the width of the *included* figure when processed using LaTeX.

Comment: +1 for a clear explanation on which settings to use and where

Comment: Thanks, Gavin, that did it for me. BTW, what's the problem with T and F? Are they problematic in Sweave, R or both?

Comment: Both; you **can't** do this in R `TRUE <- FALSE`, but you **can** do this `T <- FALSE`! `T` and `F` are shortcuts but they are reserved words so their value can be changed. Best to avoid using them.